# How do i find a control if i know only part of the AutomationId in CodedUI

Tags: c#, microsoft-ui-automation

I am trying to find a control that is like AUTO1.1.2.2.2_Status....
The part before status may change. So how should i find it onli by searching for Status.
I tried this but it is not right.

```
   uIWpfImage.SearchProperties[WpfImage.PropertyNames.AutomationId].Contains(controlPropertiesList[2]);
```

PLease Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could **get all automation elements** (via treewalker or [findall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) & store them into a [collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelementcollection(v=vs.110).aspx). Afterwards **iterate over the collection** and **check if** the automationId **[contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** the desired automation id.

Tbh I think this solution is not optimal in terms of performance, because you will need to store the collection first, before checking the property. Sadly I couldn't find a better solution yet.

---

EDIT:
The above answer focuses on UI Automation Core not Coded UI directly:
for coded UI you can try something like:

```
    control.SearchProperties.Add(
        // take some identical property here, matching all possible
        // controls (e.g. PropertyNames.Name; if that property is
        // the same for all your Images)
    );

    UITestControlCollection controlcollection = control.FindMatchingControls();
    foreach (UITestControl x in controlcollection)
    {
        if (x is WpfImage)
        {
              // cast the WpfControl to an AutomationElement
             AutomationElement temp = (AutomationElement)x;
             string automationId = temp.GetCurrentPropertyValue(
                 AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty) as string;

             if(automationId.contains("_STATUS"))
             {
                 // go on..
             }
         }
    }
```